# Access members in method when used as event handler for other object?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript "class" (if you want to call it that) similar to this:

```
function MyClass()
{
  this.something = "hello";

  this.myHandler = function(e) { console.log(this.something); };
}
var taco = new MyClass();
```

Then I have an event handler setup something like this:

```
$('div').on('click', taco.myHandler);
```

So whenever my `div` is clicked, the event handler fires. However, `this.something` comes up as `undefined`, I guess because `this` is pointing to the jQuery selector for `$('div')` instead of pointing to the class.

When a class's method is used as an event handler for another object, how do I access the class's private and public members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the function object with the actual object, like this

```
$('div').on('click', taco.myHandler.bind(taco));
```

The actual problem is, when you say `taco.myHandler` you will get just the function object. And the `this` will be assigned only when it is actually invoked. So, when the use clicks on the `div`, it will invoke the function object passed to it. Since the object associated with that is not found, by default, JavaScript will set `this` to the global `window` object, where `something` is not defined. That is why you are getting `undefined`.

When you bind the function object with the actual object, it will create a new function where the `this` binding is kept intact.